# Using some sort of loop to add to a string

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I’m trying to make a shop command that lists the items that I have added to the shop via another command. I tried to use a `for` loop to add to the string, but I had no luck with that because the values were `undefined` For some reason. At this point, I’ve switched to `forEach` in an attempt to try and make this work, but instead of each value being undefined, it only lists 1 of the 2 items saved in the database.

I am using Enmap to store the shop items.

I filter the shop items using the .filter() function which returns an Enmap (map)

**Expected Behavior:** The command properly lists all items in the shop *(in this case 2 items) and all of their values*

**Actual Behavior:** The embed only shows 1/2 of the items.

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
module.exports = {
    id: 'shop',
    aliases: ['buythings', 'linkcoinshop', 'edward'],
    channels: 'guild',
    exec: async (call) => {
        try {

            let filter = await call.client.shopData.filter(find => {
                return find.guildID === call.message.guild.id && find.forSale === true
            });
            if(filter.size === 0) return call.message.channel.send(`There are no items for sale right now.`)
            let embedDesc = '';
            console.log(filter)
                filter.forEach(found => {
                    embedDesc += `**__${found.itemName}__** \nDescription: ${found.itemDesc} \nCost: ${found.itemCost} \nQuantity: ${found.itemQuan} \n\n` 
                })
            const linkCoin = call.client.emojis.get('670675326837194782');
            const shopEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setTitle(`${linkCoin} LinkCoins Shop`)
            .setColor('BLURPLE')
            .setDescription(embedDesc);
            //.setDescription(`: **__Diamond Role__** \nDescription: Gives access to diamond only perks including special giveaways and more! \nCost: 1500${linkCoin} \nQuantity: ♾️ \n\n : **__Diamond + Role__** \nDescription: Access to all perks that Diamond gets you, but with extra abilities such as your own personal voice chats. \n`)
            call.message.channel.send(`Click on the reactions below to purchase.`)
            call.message.channel.send(shopEmbed)
        } catch(error) {
            call.message.channel.send(`Oops! That was an error! The issue has been reported to the adminstration team`);
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
};
```

If anybody has any suggestions of a better way to do this, or just a way to make this work, please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always create the minimum amount of code to illustrate your problem. It makes it easier for people to help you, and 8/10 times you will solve it yourself once you extract and isolate your problem.

Sounds like: how do I turn an array of objects into a string containing a list of the object properties?

Looks like you want to do this?

```
filter.reduce((prev, found) => `${prev}**__${found.itemName}__** \nDescription: ${found.itemDesc} \nCost: ${found.itemCost} \nQuantity: ${found.itemQuan} \n\n`, '')
```

Test case:

```
const filter = [
  {
    itemCost: 5,
    itemName: 'snt',
    itemDesc: 'desc',
    itemQuan: 8
  },
  {
    itemCost: 3,
    itemName: 'another',
    itemDesc: 'desc2',
    itemQuan: 10
  }
]
console.log(
  filter.reduce(
    (prev, found) =>
      `${prev}**__${found.itemName}__** \nDescription: ${found.itemDesc} \nCost: ${found.itemCost} \nQuantity: ${found.itemQuan} \n\n`,
    ''
  )
)
```

Output:

```
➜ t test.ts
**__snt__** 
Description: desc 
Cost: 5 
Quantity: 8 

**__another__** 
Description: desc2 
Cost: 3 
Quantity: 10
```

This should work with Enmap. Per [the API Docs](https://enmap.evie.dev/api#enmap-reduce-fn-initialvalue):

```
enmap.reduce(fn, [initialValue]) ⇒ *
Identical to Array.reduce().
```

Comment: I want it to loop through the items in the returned Enmap and push each value to a string not an array.

Comment: The filter works just fine, I just need it put into a string so I can put it in an embed.

Comment: That code returns the string you are looking for. I added the test case. You're welcome.

Comment: Or do you want one string per item? Oh, and is the Enmap not an array?

Comment: One total string is perfect. I wasn’t sure if reduce would remove the values from the enmap which is not what I want. 

Thanks for your help! I will set this as the answer for now! I will test it later on today.

Comment: I checked the Enmap API Docs. Should work just like an Array.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: What would prev be?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, there was nothing wrong with the filter or the forEach loop.

Although `.reduce()` works in my testing, I will continue to use `forEach`.

My problem was I was setting it all as the same key, which was causing Enmap to overwrite the values, hence only showing 1 of the things I added.

Thanks for all your help!

I will leave Josh's answer as the correct one since his method would work as well.